# check previous/left token in lexer

Tags: antlr4

how can I find the previous/left token in lexer
for example

```
lexer grammar TLexer;

ID     : [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9]*;
CARET  : '^';
RTN    : {someCond1}? CARET ID; // CARET not include this token
GLB    : {someCond2}? CARET ID; // CARET not include this token
```

etc

Comment: What are you trying to do ? What input do you want to parse ? Why lexer only ? Which version of ANTLR ?

Comment: tag antlr4 and version antlr 4  
for syntax highlighting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

thanks, I did it this way

```
lexer grammar TLexer;

@lexer::members {
    int lastTokenType = 0;
public void emit(Token token) {
    super.emit(token);
    lastTokenType = token.getType();
}
}

CARET  : '^';
RTN    : {someCond1&&(lastTokenType==CARET)}? ID;
GLB    : {someCond2&&(lastTokenType==CARET)}? ID;
ID     : [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9]*;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the Lexer source. The Lexer answers to nextToken() calls (from the parser). I haven't found that it keeps track of previous tokens. And there is no direct access to CARET. Given this input :

```
xyz ^abc
```

and this grammar :

```
lexer grammar TLexer;

ID     : [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9]* {System.out.println("ID ");} ;
CARET  : '^'                   {System.out.println("CARET ");} ;
WS     : [ \r\n] ;
RTN    : CARET ID {System.out.println("RTN " + _tokenStartCharIndex);} ;
```

the output is :

```
$ antlr4 TLexer.g4 
$ javac TLexer.java 
$ grun TLexer tokens -tokens -diagnostics -trace input.txt 
ID 
RTN 4
[@0,0:2='xyz',<1>,1:0]
[@1,3:3=' ',<3>,1:3]
[@2,4:7='^abc',<4>,1:4]
[@3,8:8='\n',<3>,1:8]
[@4,9:8='<EOF>',<-1>,2:9]
```

The lexer gives you a single token of type <4> (RTN) for the input `^abc`.

Comment: I know this, but I need another. i need CARET and RTN as two tokens

Comment: @BernardK Link is dead, but the WaybackMachine has [a copy](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20131023064138/http://www.antlr.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3604497), which looks a lot like [this wiki page](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2687092).